# Deserialization of JSON according provided Schema in Clojure

Tags: json, serialization, clojure, deserialization, jsonschema

Can any one advise a Clojure libarry, able to properly deserialize objects with complex field types like UUID etc.?

I would parse something like this:

**JSON**

```
{
    "_id": 42,
    "property1": "uuid-value"
}
```

According to something like this:

**Schema**

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "_id" : {"type" : "integer"},
        "property1" : {"type" : "UUID"}
    }
}
```

Into something like this:

**Clojure representation**

```
{:_id 42 :property1 UUID("uuid-value")}
```

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire ?

Comment: yes, it does perfect job in encoding part, but what I'm asking about is decoding in cheshire terms.

Comment: Take a look at [Transit format](https://github.com/cognitect/transit-format). It does not use JSON Schema, but it is expressly designed such that UUIDs, dates, and so on are converted to the programming-language-native format on decoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
(cheshire.core/parse-string "{\"_id\":\"someId\",\"property1\":\"uuid-value\"}" true)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using [json-schema](https://github.com/tatut/json-schema) library? It does seem just the thing you want.

Example

```
(ns my.app
  (:require [webjure.json-schema.validator :refer [validate]]
            [cheshire.core :as cheshire]))

     ;;; then in some function
     (validate (cheshire/parse-string json-schema)
               (cheshire/parse-string json-data))
```

Comment: I've already briefly look at json-schema. Didn't found any support for complex types, as well as decoding.
Rather it uses `cheshire/parse-string` as shown above to decode json, so it'll be just a string representation for complex types.